# Bash call exec with one additional prepended parameter

Tags: bash, mill

In some cases I need to pass in an additional prepended parameter to the command line args used when I call `exec`. How can I accomplish this?

```sh
if [ -z "$MILL_HOME" ] ; then
   exec $MILL_EXEC_PATH "$@"
else
   MILL_EXEC_ARGS=("--home" "$MILL_HOME" "$@") 
   exec $MILL_EXEC_PATH "$MILL_EXEC_ARGS"
fi
```

In the case above I am trying to make `--home $MILL_HOME` be the first argument passed in when $MILL_HOME is present.

Comment: Why are you doing `"$@"` in the else part, when you should be doing `"${MILL_EXEC_ARGS[@]}"`

Comment: Well I typed it wrong, but I think your `${MILL_EXEC_ARGS[@]}` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Inian feel free to submit your comment as the answer.

Comment: unless you plan on using the array later in the script, could you drop the array assignment and go with: `exec $MILL_EXEC_PATH --home "$MILL_HOME" "$@"` ... ??